# How can I cluster lat/long points into groups of exactly 5 nearest neighbors in R using rgeoda?

Tags: r, geometry, cluster-analysis, geospatial

I am working on clumping schools together based on their proximity to one another. For policy (budgetary) reasons, we want as many of these groups as possible to include exactly 5 schools. We have 297 schools we need to cluster, which would make 59 groups of 5 and 1 group of 3 (or something as close to that as possible). I am looking at the documentation of rgeoda (https://geodacenter.github.io/rgeoda/reference/index.html) and I'm struggling to figure out the right arguments to use.

So far I have done this:

```
literacy_geoda <- sf_to_geoda(latlong_geom)

kernel_weights(literacy_geoda)
```

I'm getting this error whenenver I try to run a function from rgeoda like the above:

Error in sf_obj[[attr(sf_obj, "sf_column")]] :
wrong arguments for subsetting an environment

> kmeansresult[["cluster"]]

I previously tried just using kmeans, which worked mostly, but I couldn't set the min or max neighbors so I'm getting groups that are way larger than 5.

```
set.seed(123)
kmeans_result <- kmeans(coords, centers = 60, iter.max = 5)

latlong_geom$cluster_school <- kmeans_result$cluster
```

Comment: Please read about [how to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) and update your question accordingly. Include a sample of your data by pasting the output of `dput(<your data frame>)` into your post or `dput(head(<your data frame>))` if you have a large data frame. If you cannot post your data, then post code for creating representative data. Please specify the packages you are using in your code too.

Answer (score 0):

Save the weights `weights <- kernel_weights(literacy_geoda)` then pass your shapes and weights to a contiguity clustering function.  In `rgeoda` you might look at the function `?gda_queen_weights` despite its present disclaimer of internal use only.  Good luck!

[Queen Contiguity at GeoDa](https://geodacenter.github.io/workbook/4a_contig_weights/lab4a.html#queen-contiguity)

Also the package authors provide an API function list online:

[rgeoda function list](https://geodacenter.github.io/rgeoda/reference/)